# HTML5 canvas clearRect() is flickering on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas

I have two equal canvases:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="512" height="512" style="background:#eeeeff"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="512" height="512" style="background:#eeffee"></canvas>
```

This code renders image on each canvas every frame:

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');

var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://colrd.com/misc/library/pattern/DinPattern/horton.gif';

var draw = function(context) {
  context.clearRect(128, 128, 256, 256);  // It causes flickering effect on Android
  // context.clearRect(0, 0, 512, 512);   // If I clear whole canvas everything is OK

  context.drawImage(image, 128, 128, 256, 256);
};

var onDraw1 = function() {
  draw(context1);
  requestAnimationFrame(onDraw1, canvas1);
};

var onDraw2 = function() {
  draw(context2);
  requestAnimationFrame(onDraw2, canvas2);
};

onDraw1();
onDraw2();
```

It works fine on major browsers but it flickers on Android Chrome and Android stock browser (try to zoom in and zoom out this example):

https://jsfiddle.net/y89m8f1L/

However, if I clear whole canvas before rendering image it's not flickering.
This problem can be reproduced by using only one canvas, but in this case flickering is not noticeable so much.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use 2 render loops? It is bad practice to use more than one! Just use the one `requestAnimationFrame(onDraw)` and draw both frames this will guarantee the content of both canvases are presented at the same time. BTW `requestAnimationFrame` only takes one argument

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter: https://jsfiddle.net/y89m8f1L/1/